# Testing independence on multivariate categorical data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, independence

Let $S_1$ = $(X_1, Y_1)$ and $S_2$ = $(X_2, Y_2)$ be two samples from two groups. The broad null hypothesis is that they come from the same distribution. Note $X$ is a matrix here with many columns and $Y$ is just a vector.

By running a random forest model and looking at the variable importance, it appears that the $X_1$ in group 1 has some predictive power on $Y_1$, but only when they are combined (I know this because I checked the conditional distributions myself), while the $X_2$ and $Y_2$ look like as if they are randomly put together. This indicates they do not come from the same distribution.

Challenges for me:

1. all the $X_1, X_2$ are ordered categorical variables.
2. the sample sizes are different.

Now I want to have a way to quantify the observation that $X$ predicts $Y$, in group 1 while they don't predict in group 2.  Ideally this is done via a statistical testing procedure.  I looked at a bunch of tests for discrete random variables.  But I cannot find a multivariate version that suits my needs.  Some assume the sample sizes are the same; others test the dependence of two random vectors.  What I'm looking for is a test that can test whether a random vector $Y$ is independent of a random matrix $X$ consisting of many random vectors as columns, such that all columns are ordered categorical.

More ideally, implementation in Python/Matlab/R would be greatly appreciated.